# Collections.sort() is giving me compilation error. How to do sort() on ArrayList<T>, where T is coming at runtime (dynamic)?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I am practicing ArrayList and I wanted to create a method that sorts the List<> of any type T (T can be Integer, String, or maybe something else).

I am aware that sort works on those classes which have implemented Comparable interface.

**Expected: sort should work if the class T (dynamically coming in the parameter) is implementing Comparable.**

**Actual:** I am stuck here as the sort is giving me compilation error :

*The method sort(List<T extends Comparable<? super T>>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List)*

I think this is because sort expected the type of List to be predefined (like Integer or String) but I am giving it T which is undefined until the program runs.

This is where my main() is (focus in last line):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        arrayListFunctions = new ArrayListFunctions();
        
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //Imagine adding some integers...

        //This line is where it begins
        arrayListFunctions.sortList(al);
    }
```

This is where **arrayListFunctions.sortList(al);** points to:

```
    <T> List<T> sortList(List<T> input) {
        if (input instanceof Comparable) {
            input = Collections.sort(input);
            System.out.println("List is sorted.");
            printUsingIterator(input);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Failed to sort as type of list is not comparable.");
            
        return input;
    }
```

Comment: The compiler error tells you how a generic method can demand comparable elements without requiring a concrete type. Just use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> sortList(List<T> input)`

Answer (score 3):

You can check if every element in the `List` is a `Comparable` and use `List#sort`.

```
<T> List<T> sortList(List<T> input) {
    if (input.stream().allMatch(Comparable.class::isInstance)) {
        input.sort(null);
        System.out.println("List is sorted.");
    } else
        System.out.println("Failed to sort as type of list is not comparable.");
    return input;
}
```

Comment: I got to know that `input.sort(null);` was enough for it to work. Thanks for giving this excellent solution.

Comment: The check is pointless. `Arrays.asList("string", 42, 0.5)` will pass the test as all elements are `Comparable`, still, the operation will fail.